# displaying available time by comparing 2 tables with a POST variable

Tags: mysql, sql

these are my tables

```
RESERVATIONS
```

```
+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
|   id   |  reservation_date  | reservation_time|
+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
|   1    | November 05, 2019  |  9:00am-12:00pm |
|   2    | November 05, 2019  |  12:00pm-3:00pm |
|   3    | November 05, 2019  |   3:00pm-6:00pm |
|   4    | November 05, 2019  |   6:00pm-9:00pm |
|   5    | November 06, 2019  |  9:00am-12:00pm |
|   6    | November 06, 2019  |  12:00pm-3:00pm |
|   7    | November 06, 2019  |   3:00pm-6:00pm |
|   8    | November 12, 2019  |  9:00am-12:00pm |
|   9    | November 13, 2019  |  9:00am-12:00pm |
+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

reservation_date is in VARCHAR format

```
TIME_AVAILABILITY
```

```
+--------+------------------+
|   id   | reservation_time |
+--------+------------------+
|   1    |  9:00am-12:00pm  |
|   2    |  12:00pm-3:00pm  |
|   3    |   3:00pm-6:00pm  |
|   4    |   6:00pm-9:00pm  |
+--------+------------------+
```

so here's the thing, I want to display the values in my TIME_AVAILABILITY table based on a $_POST variable and RESERVATIONS table. For example if a user's input is  **November 05, 2019** It will display nothing because all the values in TIME_AVAILABILITY table are already in the RESERVATIONS table, but if the user input is **November 06, 2019** it will only display **6:00pm-9:00pm**
I tried using INNER JOIN but I just can't make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TIME_AVAILABILITY` table joined to a subquery of the `RESERVATIONS` table will produce only the `null` matches (which is what you are looking for since `null` represents a `TIME_AVAILABILITY` that has not been filled for the date put in the `where` clause *your "POST" date* as it were):

```
select t.reservation_time
from TIME_AVAILABILITY t
  left join (
    select reservation_time, reservation_date
    from RESERVATIONS
    where reservation_date = 'November 05, 2019'
  ) as q
  on t.reservation_time = q.reservation_time
where q.reservation_date is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to above answer you can do it with not in clause.

```
select t.reservation_time
from TIME_AVAILABILITY t where t.reservation_time not in (
select reservation_time
    from RESERVATIONS
    where reservation_date = 'November 05, 2019'
)
```